# Save data in Edit Text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 5 Edit Texts in android for users to input number and save . I would like to know if I could have a method for checking if any  Edit Texts in already number,next number display another edit text ,but every time it override first edit text value ,Please tell me how can check edit text box not blank and number display another edit text.

```
        number1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        number2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        number3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        number4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        number5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);


        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String number = i.getStringExtra("Number"); 
        Log.e("international", "number1"+number);

        if((number1.getText().toString().equals("")))
        {
             number1.setText(number);
             Log.e("international", "number1"+number); 

        }
        else if ((!number1.getText().toString().equals("")) &&               number2.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
             number2.setText(number); 
             Log.e("international", "number2"+number); 

        }
        else if ((number1.getText().length()!=0) && (number2.getText().length()!=0) && number3.length()==0 ) 
        {
             number3.setText(number);
             Log.e("international", "number3"+number); 

        }else if (number1.length()!=0 && number2.length()!=0 && number3.length()!=0 && number4.length()==0 ) 
        {
             number4.setText(number); 

        }else if (number1.length()!=0 && number2.length()!=0 && number3.length()!=0 && number4.length()!=0 && number5.length()==0 ) 
        {
             number5.setText(number); 

        }else
        {

             number3.setText(number); 
             Log.e("international else...", "number3"+number); 
        }
```

Comment: when current code is executing on any Button click or on `onCreate` method call?

Comment: I am passing data from second activity to first activity first time  it works but all another time it replace first edit text value

Comment: is posted code is executed in `onCreate` method ?

Comment: yes,sir it executed in onCreate method